# Activating part without resolving [[1]]

Tags: evaluation, interactive, code-generation, slot

I'll try to make this question more clear in a little while.  In the mean time, I'll ask directly the question which motivated it:
[Latin Square from submatrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264329/latin-square-from-submatrix)

### Original Question

I want, for instance, to obtain the code

```
{#[[1]],
 #2[[1]],
 #3[[1]],
 ...
 #999[[1]]}
```

and I'm not sure how to do it.  If I run

```
Activate[Part[Inactive[Slot][#], 2] & /@ Range@999]
```

I get what I want, since `Slot[n]` has no second part.  How do I get the *input code* for a part of an expression that may or may not exist without having it wrapped or inactive?

---

This problem arose when writing code to solve for missing matrix entries; each missing entry got assigned a numbered `Slot`.  I may type this specific example up, but in the mean time here's a contrived example:

```
thelist=Table[#[[i]],{i,10}]&
(*Out[]={1,i[[2]],i[[3]],...,i[[10]]}*)
```

The desired output is

```
(*Out[]={i[[1]],i[[2]],i[[3]],...,i[[10]]}*)
```

Comment: Does `Indexed` have the effect you want?

Comment: I'm looking to use `Part` in a later piece of code to extract elements, I just don't want to manually type it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but does the following help?

```
thelist = Table[Indexed[#, i], {i, 10}] &
(* Table[Indexed[#1, i], {i, 10}] & *)

thelist[Range[10, 20]]
(* {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19} *)
```