# Latin Square from submatrix

Tags: matrix

A Latin Square is a $n\times n$ matrix with entries in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that

- each column has the entries $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and
- each row has the entires $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

It's a common math problem to "fill in" missing entries of a partial (claimed) Latin Square.  **I want to write a function whose input is a partially filled $n\times n$ matrix which outputs a valid Latin Square supermatrix if one exists**.  For instance,

```
7   1   4   3   2   5   6
4   3   7   6   5   2   1
1   2   6   7   4   3   5
```

are the first three rows of many valid $7\times7$ Latin Squares.  The `Null`s in the following $6\times6$ matrix can be replaced with numbers from 4 to 6 which make it a Latin Square

```
partmat={{,2,3,,,1},{2,3,,,1,},{3,,2,1,,},{,,1,2,,3},{,1,,,3,2},{1,,,3,2,}}
```

etc.  If no values are given, there is a huge amount of solutions.  But given some partially filled in matrix (say, with `Null`s), write some code to compute a valid coinciding Latin Square, and then find them all.

For the first example, I defined a function

```
allvalidnextrows[pancakerect_, n_] := 
 Select[Flatten[Outer @@ 
 Prepend[Complement[Range@7, #] & /@ (pancakerect\[Transpose]), 
 List], n - 1], Sort@# == Range@n &]
```

and used (with `rows` appropriately defined)

```
Nest[DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ ((mat \[Function] 
    Append[mat, #] & /@ allvalidnextrows[mat, 7]) /@ #)] &, {rows}, 4]
```

to find the ~11 thousand supmatrices.  For the second example, I wrote a weird function which substitutes the 18 missing values

```
matfunc = Evaluate[Activate@
Fold[{ReplacePart[#[[1]], #2 -> Inactive[Slot][#[[2]]]], #[[2]] + 
     1} &, {partmat, 1}, Position[partmat, Null]][[1]]] &
```

and then did some things I'm ashamed of to arrive at

```
MatrixForm[matfunc @@ Join @@ #] & /@ 
Flatten[Table[
If[{4, 5, 6} == Sort@{i1[[1]], i4[[1]], i5[[1]]} == 
 Sort@{i3[[1]], i4[[2]], i6[[1]]} == 
 Sort@{i2[[1]], i5[[2]], i6[[2]]} == 
 Sort@{i1[[2]], i2[[2]], i5[[3]]} == 
 Sort@{i1[[3]], i3[[2]], i4[[3]]} == 
 Sort@{i2[[3]], i3[[3]], i6[[3]]}, {i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6}, 
 Nothing], {i1, {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 6, 5}, {5, 4, 6}, {5, 6, 4}, {6, 4,
   5}, {6, 5, 4}}}, {i2, {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 6, 5}, {5, 4, 6}, {5, 6, 
  4}, {6, 4, 5}, {6, 5, 4}}}, {i3, {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 6, 5}, {5, 4, 
  6}, {5, 6, 4}, {6, 4, 5}, {6, 5, 4}}}, {i4, {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 6, 
  5}, {5, 4, 6}, {5, 6, 4}, {6, 4, 5}, {6, 5, 4}}}, {i5, {{4, 5, 
  6}, {4, 6, 5}, {5, 4, 6}, {5, 6, 4}, {6, 4, 5}, {6, 5, 
  4}}}, {i6, {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 6, 5}, {5, 4, 6}, {5, 6, 4}, {6, 4, 
  5}, {6, 5, 4}}}], 5]
```

which yields 72 supmatrices.

This question is to give context to another one, [Activating part without resolving [[1]]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264324/activating-part-without-resolving-1).  I'm curious about generality (I haven't achieved that with my code) and performance (I certainly haven't achieved that with my code).

Comment: Ummm... what's your question, exactly?

Comment: I suppose this is more suited for the Wolfram forum, but to pin down an explicit Q: how to write a function whose input is a partially filled square matrix which outputs a valid Latin Square supermatrix if there is one.

Comment: That's a valid question here... but please WRITE that question within your posting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty and not very well tested solution using recursion.

The input must consists of a matrix with elements 0..n. The 0 indicates a missing element. If no solution is possible "Nothing" is returned.

First, we need a test to see if a partial solution fulfills the conditions:

```
test[sq0_] := Module[{sq = sq0, c},
  c = 0; sq = sq /. 0 :> --c;
  AllTrue[Join[DuplicateFreeQ /@ sq , DuplicateFreeQ /@ Transpose[sq]]
   , # == True &]
  ]
```

Then we try to eliminate the zeros one at a time:

```
step[sq0_] := Module[{sq, pos, n = Length[sq0], row, t},
  If[! MemberQ[Flatten[sq0], 0], Return[{sq0}]];
  res = Reap[
     pos = FirstPosition[sq0, 0];
     (sq = sq0; sq[[Sequence @@ pos]] = #; 
        If[test[sq], Sow[step[sq]]] ) & /@ 
      Complement[Range[n], Union[sq0[[pos[[1]], All]]], 
       sq0[[All, pos[[2]]]]];
     ][[2]];
  res = Flatten[res, 2];
  If[Flatten[res] == {}, Nothing, res]
  ]
```

For a test we need a matrix: sq that fulfills the conditions:

```
While[(sq = Array[RandomInteger[{0, 3}] &, {3, 3}]; ! test[sq])];
MatrixForm[sq]
```

[image]

And then we can get the solutions:

```
MatrixForm /@ step[sq]
```

[image]

Or with a 4 times 4 matrix:

```
While[(sq = Array[RandomInteger[{0, 4}] &, {4, 4}]; ! test[sq])];
MatrixForm[sq]
MatrixForm /@ step[sq]
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `RandomInteger[{0, 4}, {4, 4}]` in place of `Array[RandomInteger...` for testing speedup?  Also, should `res` not be also declared in the `Module` instead of as a global symbol?  Also, what's with the `AllTrue[...,#==True]` -- intentionally verbose?

Comment: Also, +1, awesome answer.  A cute math problem is to find a 10x10 one whose upperleft 5x5 submatrix is the addition table mod 5.  This code doesn't fare too well -- I suppose it does BFS -- but most tricky math problems are are designed with loopholes to be infeasible with brute force.

Comment: You are right. There things to improve. I simply tried to made it work.

Comment: Here is a faster trial: `n = 5; nzero = 15;
pe = Permutations[Range[n]];
While[! test[sq = RandomChoice[Permutations[Range[n]], n]]];
sq = ReplacePart[sq, RandomInteger[{1, n}, {nzero, 2}] -> 0];
sq // MatrixForm
step[sq]`

Answer (score 2):

There is a paper (Ref. 1) that proved that a diagonal element in a Latin square doesn't occur more than twice in the diagonal. So no Latin square has a form of `partmat`. You can brute-check via:

```
partmat = {{_, 2, 3, _, _, 1}, {2, 3, _, _, 1, _}, {3, _, 2, 1, _, _}, {_, _, 1, 2, _, 3}, {_, 1, _, _, 3, 2}, {1, _, _, 3, 2, _}};
n = Length@partmat (*dimension of partmat*);
size = n!*n!;

(*produce every permutation of LS in dimension n*)
ran = Range[1, n];
seed = DeleteDuplicates[Permutations[ran], AnyTrue[Table[#1[[i]] == #2[[i]], {i, n}], TrueQ] &] (*make a seed Latin square*);
lPr = Permutations[seed] (*row permutations*);
lP = {};
Dynamic[N[Length[lP]/size]]
Do[
    lsP = lPr[[i]];
    lP = Join[lP, Transpose /@ Permutations[Transpose[lsP]]];
    Clear[lsP];
, {i, n!}]

(*search every Latin square matching partmat pattern*)
sol = Select[lP, AllTrue[Table[MatchQ[#[[i]], partmat[[i]]], {i, n}], TrueQ] &]
(* {} *)
```

---

Reference:

1. Peter J. Cameron and Ian M. Wanless, *Covering radius for sets of permutations*, 2004.

Comment: If partmat is defined with `Null`'s instead of `_`'s, then I get True out of `partmat=={{4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 5}, {3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3}, {6, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4}} /. (4 | 5 | 6) -> Null`

Comment: @Adam Apologies, I misunderstood the statement in the paper, and just realized that my code produces the squares only partially. I'll correct and update as soon as possible.